# Como configurar fontAwesome en nuxt 3?

Tags: vue3, nuxt

No puedo hacer funcionar fontawesome con nuxt 3. aparece el siguiente error:

[Failed to resolve import "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome" from "virtual:C:\Users\aleja\Documents\Proyectos\templates\store-template.nuxt\fontawesome.js". Does the file exist?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8NVb.png)

Asi esta mi package.json justo ahora:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxi dev",
    "build": "nuxi build",
    "start": "node .output/server/index.mjs"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@nuxtjs/fontawesome": "^1.1.2",
    "nuxt3": "latest",
    "sass": "^1.49.9",
    "sass-loader": "^10.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "saas": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

y este es mi archivo de configuración de Nuxt 3:

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt3'

    export default defineNuxtConfig({
        typescript: {
            shim: false
        },
       
        css:['normalize.css/normalize.css'],
        vite: {
            css: {
                preprocessorOptions: {
                    scss: {
                        additionalData: 
                            '@import "@/assets/css/_default.scss";'+
                            '@import "@/assets/css/pallete.scss";'+
                            '@import "@/assets/css/fonts.scss";'
                        
                    },
                },
            },
        },
        buildModules: ['@nuxtjs/fontawesome'],
        fontawesome:{
            component: 'fa',
            icons:{
                solid:true,
            }
        },
    })
```

Gracias. espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Asi lo especifica la documentacion.

Comment: Tenés razón, retiro lo dicho. Por otra parte, ¿revisaste [estas](https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome/issues/345) [issues](https://github.com/nuxt-community/fontawesome-module/issues/39)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El paquete @nuxtjs/fontawesome no se actualiza desde 2020, no tiene pinta que sea compatible con nuxt 3. Yo lo he configurado creando un plugin:

```
    import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome';
    import {
        faCocktail
    } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

    export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
        config.autoAddCss = false;
        library.add(faCocktail);
        nuxtApp.vueApp.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon);
    });
```

Con esto, ya se puede usar el componente font-awesome-icon en cualquier lugar sin problema.

Comment: Yo e optado por usar iconify. el cual posee los iconos de fa6. Aunque Gracias por el codigo no se me habia ocurrido algo asi.